# How to delete all Review of a News when News is deleted from db?

Tags: laravel

I have Two Models `News` and `Review`
This is `News` model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;

use Brexis\LaravelWorkflow\Traits\WorkflowTrait;
//use Hyn\Tenancy\Abstracts\TenantModel as TenancyModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

/**
 * This is for storing  news
 * Class News
 * @package Modules\Newsletter\Entities
 */
//class News extends TenancyModel {
class News extends Model {

    use WorkflowTrait;
    
    protected $table = 'news_info';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'header', 'description', 'status', 'created_by', 'media_url', 'media_thumbnail', 'media_type'
    ];

    /**
     * This creates relationship between News and Reviews
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function reviews() {
        return $this->morphMany(NewsReview::class, 'reviewable');
    }

    /**
     * This is for creating relationship between News and Review and counting reactions according to is_visible=1
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function reviewsCountByvisible() {
        return $this->morphMany(NewsReview::class, 'reviewable')
            ->select(
                'reviewable_id',
                DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN review_reaction=0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as review_bad"),
                DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN review_reaction=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as review_average"),
                DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN review_reaction=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as review_good")
            )->where('is_visible', '=', 1)
            ->groupBy('reviewable_id');
    }
}
```

This is Review model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;

use App\User;
//use Hyn\Tenancy\Abstracts\TenantModel as TenancyModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * This is for storing Reviews of a News
 * Class NewsReview
 * @package Modules\Newsletter\Entities
 */
//class NewsReview extends TenancyModel {
class NewsReview extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'review_text',
        'review_reaction',
        'is_visible',
        'reviewed_by',
        'reviewable_id',
        'reviewable_type'
    ];

    /**
     * This is for creating relation between Reviews and News
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function reviewable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function news() {
        return $this->belongsTo(News::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function reviewer() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'reviewed_by');
    }
    
}
```

This is the function I am using to delete `news`

```
public function delete($id){
        $news=News::find($id);
        $news->delete();
    }
```

I want that if I delete a news then all reviews related to this news should be deleted.
Can anyone help me.Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would advise you to set up a foreign key with DELETE ON CASCADE  constraint  in the database so when you delete new info it will automatically delete reviews record.

Comment: can this be done through migrate comand?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! You have a polymorphic relationship setup between NewsReviews and News.  So, foreign key constraint won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by using model events defined in your AppServiceProvider file :

```
public function boot()
{
    News::deleted(function (News $$news) {
       $news->reviews()->delete();
    });
}
```

Comment: no. it is not working. 
I pasted the your boot method in app service provider 
can you tel me how we will use this boot method?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below working example of morphMany relation model delete. My News model is :

```
class News extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';
    
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Review', 'reviewable');
    }
}
```

And this is review model

```
class Review extends Model
{
    public function reviewable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

`$news->reviews()` is the relationship query to return all of the reviews for a news. If you call `delete()` on that, it will delete all of those records.

```
$news = News::find(1);
$news->reviews()->delete();
```

Please Replace your code, this:

```
public function delete($id){
        $news=News::find($id);
        $news->delete();
    }
```

To this :

```
public function delete($id){
        $news=News::find($id);
        $news->reviews()->delete();
        $news->delete();
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220079/discussion-on-answer-by-vinod-how-to-delete-all-review-of-a-news-when-news-is-de).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using events as already suggested, you could also override your News' `delete` method and handle deletion there:

```php
class News {

    public function delete(){
        // delete associated reviews
        $this->reviews()->delete();
        // call parent delete, which deletes the model itself
        parent::delete();
    }

}
```

This will only work when directly calling the delete method on a news instance though.

You could also take care of that at the database level via [constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints). E.g. by definining:

```php
Schema::table('news_reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('news_id');

    $table->foreign('news_id')->references('id')->on('news')
        ->onDelete('cascade'); // this will 

});
```

This has the advantage that you are guaranteed to never have any stray reviews left in your database and that you don't have to manually delete reviews, BUT your application will not be notified when reviews are deleted (because it happens at the database level) and it's less obvious for other developers, so you should document that behaviour.

Comment: I have to create event for this?

Comment: Ahmed Atoui's answer uses events